# How can I use css for Vaadin 7 components?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

I've set the styleName for my component, but it doesn't appear to have any effect:

```
Label  label=new Label("this is test");
label.setStyleName("mytheme");
```

My CSS:

```
@import "../reindeer/styles.css";

.test{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}


.mytheme {
    font-family: 'Cabin Sketch';
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.v-label {
    background: cyan;
}
```

My directory in intellij IDE: `web/VAADIN/themes/mytheme`

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274816/how-can-i-use-css-for-vaadin-components), but the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: How are you calling/defining the theme (maybe I'm using the default theme)?

Comment: solution: 
in vaadin 7:
Vaadin/themes/mytheme/styles.scss
in styles.scss:
@import url(../reindeer/legacy-styles.css);

Comment: as described in the docs: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.creating.html

Comment: I thought you were using CSS (plain old css in vaadin), but you are using SCSS. Why did not understand your problem. The link that @cfrick posted, will help you!

Comment: Also note that it is generally better to Use addStyleName() instead of setStyleName() as it preserves other styles already present on your component.

Answer (score 0):

input in main class: 
@Theme("mytheme")

[image]

and use in all project by `component.setStyleName("Logo");`