# How can i apply CSS to components in VAADIN 8

Tags: css, sass, vaadin8

I am trying to apply CSS to Vaadin 8 component. I have followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274816/how-can-i-use-css-for-vaadin-components/14319163) and still unable to apply CSS. I understand that i can call the addStyleName method and i am able to apply the build in ValoTheme styles (for example ValoTheme.PANEL_BORDERLESS does make a button smaller), but my custom styles are ignored. I have tried defining my custom CSS rules in the following files:

/src/Main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/apptheme/styles.css

```
@import "../reindeer/styles.css";

.mystyle {
    color: red;
    background: #012345;
    background-color: #012345;
}
```

Then in Java i create a button:

```
Button btn = new Button(" Test ");
  btn.addStyleName("mystyle");
```

My custom style does not get applied to the button. I suspect that i am not defining CSS correctly. Please share your knowledge of how to do this correctly in Vaadin 8.

Comment: `apptheme.scss`...  do you compile this scss file to css before packaging the application? i don't believe vaadin understands scss. In your linked example, they don't use scss

Comment: i have tried to use both: scss and plain css. I will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not related, but are you actually using a `reindeer` theme?*

Otherwise, you should put you styles in your own theme file (the default one generated from an archetype is `mytheme.scss`)

It's suggested to leave `styles.scss` as it is. Also, it's mentioned in comments section of the file:

> This file prefixes all rules with the theme name to avoid causing conflicts with other themes. The actual styles should be defined in mytheme.scss

If you want, you could add your styles there as well under

```
.mytheme {

  @include addons;
  @include mytheme;

  .testStyle{
    color: red;
    background: #012345;
    background-color: #012345;
  }
}
```

While it works, I will still suggest to add them to your custom scss file (Based on your folder name it is `apptheme.scss`)

Mine `mytheme.scss` looks like this:

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  .testStyle{
    color: red;
    background: #012345;
    background-color: #012345;
  }
}
```

After styles are applied, button looks like this:

[image]

*Style files are located under `webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme`*